# MahApps.Metro Flyout not overlaying a column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a simple layout and am trying to put in a flyout to use as a user input screen.  Here's the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Add New Task" Command="{Binding NewTaskCommand}" Margin="{StaticResource CenteredToolMargin}"/>
        <Button Content="Archive Tasks" Command="{Binding ArchiveTasksCommand}" Margin="{StaticResource CenteredToolMargin}"/>
        <Button Content="Complete Tasks" Command="{Binding CompleteTasksCommand}" Margin="{StaticResource CenteredToolMargin}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Controls:Flyout Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200" IsOpen="True">
        <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
            <TextBlock FontSize="24">Hello World</TextBlock>
        </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
    </Controls:Flyout>
</Grid>
```

The problem is, the flyout appears to the left of column 1 instead of on top of it.  When I close the flyout, it animates over column 1, though.  I tried swapping the "Controls:Flyout" and "Controls:FlyoutsControl" tags as I can't find consistent guidance on which way they should go, but it acts the same, either way.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I did look there, problem is, their docs are a bit outdated I think as "<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>" doesn't exist which is why I went looking elsewhere

Comment: Yes, MetroWindow exists, but the only thing IN MetroWindow is FlyoutStatusChanged and WindowTransitionCompleted.

Comment: It shows up just fine, but it shows up to the left of column 1 (see the code I posted) instead of overlaying the entire right side of the window.  I've tried putting it in the grid, tried changing the placement of the tags, etc.  Not sure why it isn't overlaying column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the Column 1 Width to Auto if you want your fixed width than in Flyout add this line `Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` and remove `Grid.Column="1"`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Add New Task" />
        <Button Content="Archive Tasks" />
        <Button Content="Complete Tasks" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Controls:Flyout Grid.Column="1" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200" IsOpen="True">
        <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
            <TextBlock FontSize="24">Hello World</TextBlock>
        </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
    </Controls:Flyout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the expected behavior

Comment: Okay i was thinking you are taking about flyout closing event which overlay another column even if it is on another column

Comment: @linus72982 Answer Updated